# Why does Material UI's "withStyles" not allow camelCase props?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

While working with the new Material UI (version 1.0.0-beta.33 as of this post), I'm having a lot of trouble with prop casing. It seems as if `withStyles` arbitrarily allows camelCased props in some cases and not in others.

For example:

```
<ChipInput
    dataSource={defaultGroups}
    defaultValue={this.state.groups}
    fullWidth={true}
    label="Test Groups"
    newChipKeyCodes={[9, 13, 32, 186, 188]}
    onChange={chips => this.submitForm(field, this.state.groups, chips.toString())}
    openOnFocus={true}
/>
```

I've seen this repeatedly while working with the latest Material UI. In this case I'm using a prop called `openOnFocus` with the `Material-ui-chip-input` library (version 1.0.0-beta.3) and I'm getting this error in the console:

```
Warning: React does not recognize the `openOnFocus` prop on a DOM element. 
If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, 
spell it as lowercase `openonfocus` instead. If you accidentally passed it 
from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
in div (created by Input)
in Input (created by WithStyles(Input))
in WithStyles(Input) (created by ChipInput)
in div (created by ChipInput)
in div (created by FormControl)
in FormControl (created by WithStyles(FormControl))
in WithStyles(FormControl) (created by ChipInput)
in ChipInput (created by WithStyles(ChipInput))
in WithStyles(ChipInput)
in div
in Unknown (created by ConnectedField)
in ConnectedField (created by Connect(ConnectedField))
in Connect(ConnectedField) (created by Field)
in Field (created by TestMethodDetails)
in div (created by TestMethodDetails)
in div (created by TestMethodDetails)
in div (created by TestMethodDetails)
in form (created by TestMethodDetails)
in div (created by TestMethodDetails)
in TestMethodDetails (created by Form(TestMethodDetails))
in Form(TestMethodDetails) (created by Connect(Form(TestMethodDetails)))
in Connect(Form(TestMethodDetails)) (created by ReduxForm)
in ReduxForm (created by Connect(ReduxForm))
in Connect(ReduxForm) (created by ProjectTestMethodView)
in div (created by ProjectTestMethodView)
in ProjectTestMethodView (created by Connect(ProjectTestMethodView))
in Connect(ProjectTestMethodView) (created by Route)
in Route (created by ProjectView)
in div (created by ProjectView)
in div (created by ProjectView)
in ProjectView (created by Connect(ProjectView))
in Connect(ProjectView) (created by Route)
in Route (created by App)
in Switch (created by App)
in div (created by App)
in section (created by Content)
in Content (created by Connect(Content))
in Connect(Content) (created by Layout)
in div (created by Layout)
in Layout (created by App)
in div (created by App)
in MuiThemeProvider (created by App)
in App (created by Connect(App))
in Connect(App) (created by Route)
in Route (created by withRouter(Connect(App)))
in withRouter(Connect(App))
in Router (created by ConnectedRouter)
in ConnectedRouter
in AppContainer
in Provider
```

Why am I not able to use `openOnFocus` with Material UI themes, but it doesn't complain about other props like `fullWidth`? I can use camelCase props on normal react components just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't that `material-ui` won't accept camel case props. You can confirm that by looking at [all these](https://material-ui-next.com/api/button-base/) [components](https://material-ui-next.com/api/badge/) [with](https://material-ui-next.com/api/bottom-navigation/) [camel case props](https://material-ui-next.com/api/collapse/).

The problem is that React will [only accept certain props on DOM elements](https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html). So, if an HTML tag receives a prop that React doesn't recognize, you'll get the warning you mentioned. You can reproduce that with the following snippet:

```
<button someRidiculousAndClearlyInvalidProp={this.myFunc} />
```

I cannot give you the specific place that is happening because I cannot reproduce your problem with `ChipInput` and `openOnFocus` (material-ui version 0.20.0 and material-ui-chip-input 0.18.6). If you provide your exact version numbers (or better yet a CodePen) I can take a look and see if I can find the exact problem.

However, I'd like to note that this warning is often caused by the following pattern:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const { oneProp, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div {...other}>
      { oneProp ? "set" : "not set"}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Notice that the `MyComponent` takes all unused props, stores them in `other`, and the spreads them down to the child with `...other`. That pattern is great because it makes for a very flexible API. For example, this pattern allows a client to set the `onMouseEnter` or some other arbitrary prop on the `div` in ways that the component designer might not have planned for.

However, consider what happens if the client accidentally passes down an unused props like `someRidiculousAndClearlyInvalidProp`. The prop will end up in `...other`, and then be spread the `div`, causing the unknown prop warning.

This pattern is very common in material-ui. You can see examples of it [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/src/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.js) for example (just search for `...other` to find the example). If I had to bet, I would think that a component with this pattern and a misplaced, misspelled, or forgotten prop are the source of your problems.

### Edit with reproduction

Yup, that's exactly what I thought. The `openOnFocus` prop has been removed from version 1 of `material-ui-chip-input`. You can see that it's no longer [in the docs](https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-chip-input/blob/next/README.md) and [it's been commented out of the source code](https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-chip-input/blob/next/src/ChipInput.js). Look at line 411, for example.

Since `openOnFocus` is no longer a valid prop, it functions the same way as `someRidiculousAndClearlyInvalidProp` with an error getting thrown from the exact mechanism I described above.

So, again, material-ui definitely has no problems with camel case props. Instead, this error is almost always caused by invalid props getting spread down to a root component. So just go through everywhere you see this error and check to make sure you've got everything right and are using documented, valid props.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but you seem to have missed a few details in my post. I asked specifically about "withStyles" in the new "Material UI", not just material UI itself. I mentioned the versions I'm using as well. Version **1.0.0-beta.33** for **Material UI** and **1.0.0-beta.3** for **Material-ui-chip-input**. Using camelCase props is fine until I wrap a MUI component and attempt to pass props to it using camelCase. Then it complains.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your problem with the version numbers specified. I updated my answer correspondingly.